# How can I retrieve zip file from MySQL blob in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a problem during C# programming.

There is a MySQL table with longBlob type column.
LongBlob column is included zip file.
I tried to retrieve zip file from there,
but retrieved file wasn't valid zip file.

MySQL is working on linux system,
I want to retrieve zip file on windows system.

My code is below. What was wrong? 
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;

            MySqlDataReader reader = new MySqlDataReader();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();

            byte[] data = (byte[])reader["ZipFileColumn"];
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\test\test.zip", data);
            /* Zip file wasn't valid. */

            byte[] data2 = (byte[])reader["textFileColumn"];
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\test\test.txt", data2);
            /* In case of text file, it was OK. */

        }
```

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8258375/2495004
You should use GetBytes method of MySqlDataReader

Comment: I already tried this. But it does not working. I'm really want to know why only zip file doesn't working.